# How to persist IFormFile Upload when (ModelState.IsValid == false) on ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When uploading a file through a form with Asp.Net Core MVC Pattern, data on Inputs are persisted thanks to model binding. However, when I declare a property of type `IFormFile` with `[NotMapped]` attribute to act as a Data Transfer Object for file uploads, data is carried but not persisted, hence, if `ModelState.IsValid` validation fails, I will need to load the files and images again into the form in order to re-submit.

Is there any way to persist (not Store) this data when returning an ASP.NET Core MVC View?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to re-select the file after returning the ViewModel from server to client.

For a workaround, you may consider checking the Model at client side like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="File" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="File" type="file"  class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="File" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```